# How to mock a custom async React hook including useRef() with jest and react-testing-library to access result.current in Typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, jestjs, mocking, react-testing-library

I have a custom hook which includes a reference. How do I properly test such a hook and how do I mock the useRef()?

```
const useCustomHook = (
  ref: () => React.RefObject<Iref>
): {
  initializedRef: boolean
} => {
  const [initializedRef, setInitializedRef] = useState<boolean>(false)

  useEffect(() => {
    if (ref) {
      const { current } = ref()
      // here comes your ref code
      console.log({ refCurrent: current })
    }
    setInitializedRef(true)
  }, [ref])

  return { initializedRef }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here are two possibilities:

1. view solution

   ```
   import React, { useEffect, useRef, useState } from 'react'
   import { renderHook, RenderHookResult, waitFor } from '@testing-library/react'

   interface Iref {
     current: any
   }

   const useCustomHookView = (
     view: RenderHookResult<React.RefObject<Iref>, unknown>
   ): {
     initializedView: boolean
   } => {
     const [initializedView, setInitializedView] = useState<boolean>(false)

     useEffect(() => {
       if (view && view.result) {
         console.log({ viewResult: view.result.current })
       }
       setInitializedView(true)
     }, [view])
     return { initializedView }
   }

   describe('useRefMock', () => {
     beforeEach(() => {
       jest.clearAllMocks()
     })
       it('view', async () => {
         const view = renderHook(() =>
           useRef<Iref>({ current: 'my fake' })
         )

         const { result, rerender } = renderHook(() => useCustomHookView(view))
         rerender()
         expect(result.current.initializedView).toBeTruthy()
       })
   })
   ```
2. ref solution

   ```
   import React, { useEffect, useRef, useState } from 'react'
   import { renderHook, RenderHookResult, waitFor } from '@testing-library/react'

   interface Iref {
     current: any
   }

   const useCustomHookRef = (
     ref: () => React.RefObject<Iref>
   ): {
     initializedRef: boolean
   } => {
     const [initializedRef, setInitializedRef] = useState<boolean>(false)

     useEffect(() => {
       if (ref) {
         const { current } = ref()
         console.log({ refCurrent: current })
       }
       setInitializedRef(true)
     }, [ref])

     return { initializedRef }
   }

   describe('useRefMock', () => {
     beforeEach(() => {
       jest.clearAllMocks()
     })

     it('ref', async () => {
       const ref = (): React.RefObject<Iref> => {
         const { result } = renderHook(() => useRef<Iref>({ current: 'my fake' }))

         console.log({ resultCurrent: result.current })

         return result
       }

       const { result, rerender } = renderHook(() => useCustomHookRef(ref))
       rerender()
       expect(result.current.initializedRef).toBeTruthy()
   })
   ```